# Invalid compose name even docker-compose.yaml exists

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, rasa, okteto

I try to upload my rasa chatbot with okteto via docker. So i has implemented a "Dockerfile", a "docker-compose.yaml" and a "okteto.yaml". The last past weeks the code works fine. Today it wont work anymore because Okteto gives the error: Invalid compose name: must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric characterexit status 1.
I really dont understand what i should change. thanks

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  rasa-server:
    image: rasa-bot:latest
    working_dir: /app
    build: "./"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./actions:/app/actions
    - ./data:/app/data
    command: bash -c "rm -rf .rasa/* && rasa train && rasa run --enable-api --cors \"*\" -p 5006"
    ports:
    - '5006:5006'
    networks:
    - all

  rasa-actions-server:
    image: rasa-bot:latest
    working_dir: /app
    build: "./"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./actions:/app/actions
    command: bash -c "rasa run actions"
    ports:
    - '5055:5055'
    networks:
    - all

networks:
  all:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "true"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.13 AS BASE


WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["./bot.py"]

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
RUN pip install rasa==3.3.0


ADD config.yml config.yaml
ADD domain.yml domain.yaml
ADD credentials.yml credentials.yaml
ADD endpoints.yml endpoints.yaml
```

okteto.yml:

```
name: stubu4ewi
autocreate: true
image: okteto.dev/rasa-bot:latest
command: bash
volumes:
  - /root/.cache/pip
sync:
  - .:/app
forward:
  - 5006:5006
reverse:
  - 9000:9000
```

Error

```
Found okteto manifest on /okteto/src/okteto.yml
Unmarshalling manifest...
Okteto manifest unmarshalled successfully
Found okteto compose manifest on docker-compose.yaml
Unmarshalling compose...
x  Invalid compose name: must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and must start and end with an alphanumeric characterexit 
status 1
```

Dont have any clue what went wrong. It works fine till yesterday and even when nothings changed okteto gives this error.

Tried to rename the docker-compose.yaml to: docker-compose.yml, okteto-compose.yml

Comment: Unrelated to your question, the okteto.yml format you use is very old. Did you get if from a sample? https://www.okteto.com/docs/reference/manifest-migration/ has information on how to update it.

Comment: Of course ! I build the okteto.yml based on youtube tutorials how to deploy a rasa chatbot and there is no updated [video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZqoERJ-23o&t=2355s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you everr face the Problem: Rename your Repo so that it consists only of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', and starts and ends with an alphanumeric character.

Seems like Okteto uses the Repository Name to build the Images.

Answer (score 0):

That error is not about the file's name itself but the name of the services defined inside your docker-compose.yaml file.

What command did you run, and what version of the okteto cli are you using? `okteto version` will give it to you.

Comment: Thank ´s for your reply @Ramiro: I am using okteto version 2.9.0.

Comment: What command did you run @TimLange?

Comment: I run okteto version:
(env) timlange@Tims-MBP StuBu4EWI % okteto version
okteto version 2.9.0 

But for deployment i only pushed the code to github and then Launch the Dev environment frrom Github